# PHP cURL Not Fetching Image

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to display an image by fetching it through cURL but nothing is being displayed. The headers are being sent correctly so where should I look next?

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    //$imgurl = $_GET['img'];

    $query = curl_init();
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: maxage=. $cache_expire';
    $headers[] = 'Pragma: public';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: None';
    //curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_URL, "http://static4.fjcdn.com/comments/3885449+_bf7680ea243464ace7ddb3d912c7c7d6.jpg");
    curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
    curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $ret = curl_exec($query);
    if(!preg_match("/Content-Type\: image(.*)\r\n/i", $ret, $mime))
    die("die potato!");
    header($mime[0]);
    echo substr(strstr($ret, "\r\n\r\n"), 4);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` from your code. `CURLOPT_HEADER` includes response header in the response. This will make your image malformed.

Following code will work just fine.

```
function curlHeaderCallback($query, $header){
    if(stripos($header, "content-type")!==false){
        header(trim($header));
    }
    return strlen($header); 
}

$query = curl_init("http://bd1.php.net/images/php.gif");
curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'curlHeaderCallback'); 
curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$ret = curl_exec($query);
echo $ret;
```

Comment: +1 for removing header. -1 for not noticing the OP is then later stripping the header via the strstr() call. So... +0

Comment: If I do that it dies due to not being able to get the header :)

Comment: @user1811105 see the code I have given It works fine! Just change the url.

Comment: To catch the mime type you can use CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION option. See my update

Comment: It's not setting the header correctly since it just returns GIF89axCæj‚¸97G(%*ÌÍâ¡¤ËÓÕç²´ÔCBXƒ†¹‚ƒ³RRr’ÂÂÄÞª¬ÐLKc[\ƒÝÞì;8qLL>> .... etc.

Comment: @user1811105 yea. `$mime = $mime[0];` was wrong. It should be `$mime = $m[0];`. Now I updated with correct code.

Comment: It's doing the same thing as my script, showing an image that has errors in it ie. nothing. Maybe a server config issue?

Comment: @user1811105 What error is showing? The snippet I gave you works very well. Just copy it in a single php file and execute it. You'll see how it works. See this http://codepad.viper-7.com/Yth2c6

Comment: I did, and it's telling me the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: @user1811105 Did you see this? http://codepad.viper-7.com/i30TT5# I think I asked you what is the error.

Comment: Ugh nevermind, I had the ?> at the end, removing it fixed it.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then may be you are echoing other characters outside this image. Did you try same code I wrote on a separate PHP file?

Comment: Yeah see comment above. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you complicating things? How about this way:

```
$img_url = 'http://static4.fjcdn.com/comments/3885449+_bf7680ea243464ace7ddb3d912c7c7d6.jpg';
$content = file_get_contents( $img_url );
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $content;
```

Comment: It requires `allow_url_fopen ` to be `ON`. Which is not available in windows and disabled in many shared hosting.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I just run the code on my Windows 7 default apache settings. Worked fine.

Comment: And I'm using this to keep SSL on my site. It is for my users signatures. So I need it to use cURL's useragent feature so there is limited chance of it failing.

Comment: @DainisAbols sorry. I mixed up it with `allow_url_include`. But allow_url_fopen can not be used on many shared servers due to restrictions. This is one of the reasons why newbie php developers started using curl.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I'm not using a shared server, I just want to be able to specify a useragent. That is why I'm using cURL.

Comment: @user1811105 that can be added with file_get_contents too. But I think you'll need curl. As you require useragent you might require cookies too.